# Reincluding header with different #defines

Tags: c++, header, include, precompiled-headers

I've been learning more about headers, translation units, and precompiled headers lately. I think I understand them well now. I do have a couple queries though, I'll just ask one here. This is just a theoretical example so it may or may not work in practice, but please try to understand what I'm asking.

Say I have a precompiled header like so:

```
// stdafx.h

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
```

and some source file.

```
// foo.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <Windows.h>

void bar()
{
    // I need to access something in Windows.h that requires
    // WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN to NOT be defined.
}
```

It doesn't have to be precompiled headers, but any similar structure in general, though I'm not sure it'd apply otherwise. I can work around this problem with Windows.h easily enough, but I'm sure there are much more difficult situations.

Is it possible in anyway to remove the currently included Windows.h from the precompiled header and reinclude it with adjusted #defines. #undef won't work to my understanding.

The only solution that comes to mind is to create a separate source file and mark it as not using precompiled headers. I'd like to learn of any alternatives.

Also, what would be a more general way to express what I'm asking for the sake of future endeavors and search engine results?

Comment: I guess you would have to be sure that the definitions in the h file are mutually exclusive based on the parameter, unless you protect common defintions from being redefined in second include. But if you need this, consider dividing into 2 h-files instead.

Comment: Certainly, we don't want duplicate definitions. The idea would be to remove the existing include from the precompiled header, and reinclude it in the context of the current translation unit. However depending on the requirements of precompilation, that may not be possible, or at least the requirements may not be worth the investment. As a perfectionist of sorts, I try to avoid any levels of redirection until necessary, so I actually like when I'm forced with such choices. I don't particularly like defining the same tokens over again in every file though, I do it for completeness.